GCC spends time managing the stack and allocating memory for simply returning the size of a const local std::vector
(I'm not facing any issue. I know that constexpr/consteval-ifying the function below vaporises it, I know I can just implement it as return 3; and so on. I was just interested in knowning if there was any good reason why GCC is generating all that code.)
Is this a bug of GCC?
I would expect such a function
#include <vector>
int foo() {
    std::vector<int> const v{17,2,3};
    return v.size();
}

to compile down to the assembly corresponding to return 3;, and that's indeed the assembly produced by Clang:
foo():
        mov     eax, 3
        ret

But GCC generates this (yes, with -O3):
foo():
        sub     rsp, 8
        mov     edi, 12
        call    operator new(unsigned long)
        mov     esi, 12
        movabs  rdx, 8589934609
        mov     QWORD PTR [rax], rdx
        mov     rdi, rax
        mov     DWORD PTR [rax+8], 3
        call    operator delete(void*, unsigned long)
        mov     eax, 3
        add     rsp, 8
        ret

That looks a lot, if the net effect is just that eax is assigned 3 before returning.
Here is the example on CE.

This is a missed optimization at best, not a bug. Compiler are not guaranteed to generate an optimal code. They do their best (while trying not to take too much time to build files too). I am not sure GCC has such optimisation implemented yet.

I suppose a reason for the missed optimization might be related to the fact that the code of foo is simply not realistic code?

This seems legit to me. If your vector was a constant, then I would argue that it is better to add static. See the result here. It is not optimal due to the guard check but pretty good (especially since the je is nearly never taken so the CPU can predict it nearly perfectly).

An alternative solution might be to allocate some space on the stack and use a custom allocator so to avoid expensive global heap allocations. This is more expensive than using static for constants but significantly cheaper for non-constant (especially in parallel codes).

I do not fully agree with Clang's optimization here: it ignores the case where std::vector::vector throws an exception (due to low memory or whatever). Maybe GCC is being conservative?
